# Проблема с разделителем (divider) в AnimatedExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Нужно сделать разварачиваемый анимированый список я нашел вот этот код

https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView

И вроде все работает как нужно, но есть проблема когда мне нужно задать для группы цвет разделителя один, а для `childViews` в этой групе другой

Насколько я понимаю то это кастомное `AnimatedExpandableListView` вью при разворачивании перересовывает разделитель для детей, но почему то в момент анимации оно перересовывает разделитель детей разделителем от группы, а когда анимация заканчивается то остается только разделитель который задан для `childView`

вот видео, обратите внимание что при разворачивании разделитель детей красного цвета а в конце синий

https://youtu.be/WW69QUMYa1s

Вот XML

```
<com.idunnololz.widgets.AnimatedExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:divider="#f40303"
    android:childDivider="#0323f4"
    android:dividerHeight="1.5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот `AnimatedExpandableListView`

```
public class AnimatedExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {
/*
 * A detailed explanation for how this class works:
 *
 * Animating the ExpandableListView was no easy task. The way that this
 * class does it is by exploiting how an ExpandableListView works.
 *
 * Normally when {@link ExpandableListView#collapseGroup(int)} or
 * {@link ExpandableListView#expandGroup(int)} is called, the view toggles
 * the flag for a group and calls notifyDataSetChanged to cause the ListView
 * to refresh all of it's view. This time however, depending on whether a
 * group is expanded or collapsed, certain childViews will either be ignored
 * or added to the list.
 *
 * Knowing this, we can come up with a way to animate our views. For
 * instance for group expansion, we tell the adapter to animate the
 * children of a certain group. We then expand the group which causes the
 * ExpandableListView to refresh all views on screen. The way that
 * ExpandableListView does this is by calling getView() in the adapter.
 * However since the adapter knows that we are animating a certain group,
 * instead of returning the real views for the children of the group being
 * animated, it will return a fake dummy view. This dummy view will then
 * draw the real child views within it's dispatchDraw function. The reason
 * we do this is so that we can animate all of it's children by simply
 * animating the dummy view. After we complete the animation, we tell the
 * adapter to stop animating the group and call notifyDataSetChanged. Now
 * the ExpandableListView is forced to refresh it's views again, except this
 * time, it will get the real views for the expanded group.
 *
 * So, to list it all out, when {@link #expandGroupWithAnimation(int)} is
 * called the following happens:
 *
 * 1. The ExpandableListView tells the adapter to animate a certain group.
 * 2. The ExpandableListView calls expandGroup.
 * 3. ExpandGroup calls notifyDataSetChanged.
 * 4. As an result, getChildView is called for expanding group.
 * 5. Since the adapter is in "animating mode", it will return a dummy view.
 * 6. This dummy view draws the actual children of the expanding group.
 * 7. This dummy view's height is animated from 0 to it's expanded height.
 * 8. Once the animation completes, the adapter is notified to stop
 *    animating the group and notifyDataSetChanged is called again.
 * 9. This forces the ExpandableListView to refresh all of it's views again.
 * 10.This time when getChildView is called, it will return the actual
 *    child views.
 *
 * For animating the collapse of a group is a bit more difficult since we
 * can't call collapseGroup from the start as it would just ignore the
 * child items, giving up no chance to do any sort of animation. Instead
 * what we have to do is play the animation first and call collapseGroup
 * after the animation is done.
 *
 * So, to list it all out, when {@link #collapseGroupWithAnimation(int)} is
 * called the following happens:
 *
 * 1. The ExpandableListView tells the adapter to animate a certain group.
 * 2. The ExpandableListView calls notifyDataSetChanged.
 * 3. As an result, getChildView is called for expanding group.
 * 4. Since the adapter is in "animating mode", it will return a dummy view.
 * 5. This dummy view draws the actual children of the expanding group.
 * 6. This dummy view's height is animated from it's current height to 0.
 * 7. Once the animation completes, the adapter is notified to stop
 *    animating the group and notifyDataSetChanged is called again.
 * 8. collapseGroup is finally called.
 * 9. This forces the ExpandableListView to refresh all of it's views again.
 * 10.This time when the ListView will not get any of the child views for
 *    the collapsed group.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = AnimatedExpandableListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * The duration of the expand/collapse animations
 */
private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 300;

private AnimatedExpandableListAdapter adapter;

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * @see ExpandableListView#setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter)
 */
public void setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Make sure that the adapter extends AnimatedExpandableListAdapter
    if(adapter instanceof AnimatedExpandableListAdapter) {
        this.adapter = (AnimatedExpandableListAdapter) adapter;
        this.adapter.setParent(this);
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(adapter.toString() + " must implement AnimatedExpandableListAdapter");
    }
}

/**
 * Expands the given group with an animation.
 * @param groupPos The position of the group to expand
 * @return  Returns true if the group was expanded. False if the group was
 *          already expanded.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public boolean expandGroupWithAnimation(int groupPos) {
    boolean lastGroup = groupPos == adapter.getGroupCount() - 1;
    if (lastGroup && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return expandGroup(groupPos, true);
    }

    int groupFlatPos = getFlatListPosition(getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPos));
    if (groupFlatPos != -1) {
        int childIndex = groupFlatPos - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (childIndex < getChildCount()) {
            // Get the view for the group is it is on screen...
            View v = getChildAt(childIndex);
            if (v.getBottom() >= getBottom()) {
                // If the user is not going to be able to see the animation
                // we just expand the group without an animation.
                // This resolves the case where getChildView will not be
                // called if the children of the group is not on screen

                // We need to notify the adapter that the group was expanded
                // without it's knowledge
                adapter.notifyGroupExpanded(groupPos);
                return expandGroup(groupPos);
            }
        }
    }

    // Let the adapter know that we are starting the animation...
    adapter.startExpandAnimation(groupPos, 0);
    // Finally call expandGroup (note that expandGroup will call
    // notifyDataSetChanged so we don't need to)
    return expandGroup(groupPos);
}

/**
 * Collapses the given group with an animation.
 * @param groupPos The position of the group to collapse
 * @return  Returns true if the group was collapsed. False if the group was
 *          already collapsed.
 */
public boolean collapseGroupWithAnimation(int groupPos) {
    int groupFlatPos = getFlatListPosition(getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPos));
    if (groupFlatPos != -1) {
        int childIndex = groupFlatPos - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (childIndex >= 0 && childIndex < getChildCount()) {
            // Get the view for the group is it is on screen...
            View v = getChildAt(childIndex);
            if (v.getBottom() >= getBottom()) {
                // If the user is not going to be able to see the animation
                // we just collapse the group without an animation.
                // This resolves the case where getChildView will not be
                // called if the children of the group is not on screen
                return collapseGroup(groupPos);
            }
        } else {
            // If the group is offscreen, we can just collapse it without an
            // animation...
            return collapseGroup(groupPos);
        }
    }

    // Get the position of the firstChild visible from the top of the screen
    long packedPos = getExpandableListPosition(getFirstVisiblePosition());
    int firstChildPos = getPackedPositionChild(packedPos);
    int firstGroupPos = getPackedPositionGroup(packedPos);

    // If the first visible view on the screen is a child view AND it's a
    // child of the group we are trying to collapse, then set that
    // as the first child position of the group... see
    // {@link #startCollapseAnimation(int, int)} for why this is necessary
    firstChildPos = firstChildPos == -1 || firstGroupPos != groupPos ? 0 : firstChildPos;

    // Let the adapter know that we are going to start animating the
    // collapse animation.
    adapter.startCollapseAnimation(groupPos, firstChildPos);

    // Force the listview to refresh it's views
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return isGroupExpanded(groupPos);
}

private int getAnimationDuration() {
    return ANIMATION_DURATION;
}

/**
 * Used for holding information regarding the group.
 */
private static class GroupInfo {
    boolean animating = false;
    boolean expanding = false;
    int firstChildPosition;

    /**
     * This variable contains the last known height value of the dummy view.
     * We save this information so that if the user collapses a group
     * before it fully expands, the collapse animation will start from the
     * CURRENT height of the dummy view and not from the full expanded
     * height.
     */
    int dummyHeight = -1;
}

/**
 * A specialized adapter for use with the AnimatedExpandableListView. All
 * adapters used with AnimatedExpandableListView MUST extend this class.
 */
public static abstract class AnimatedExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private SparseArray<GroupInfo> groupInfo = new SparseArray<GroupInfo>();
    private AnimatedExpandableListView parent;

    private static final int STATE_IDLE = 0;
    private static final int STATE_EXPANDING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_COLLAPSING = 2;

    private void setParent(AnimatedExpandableListView parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getRealChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getRealChildTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public abstract View getRealChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
    public abstract int getRealChildrenCount(int groupPosition);

    private GroupInfo getGroupInfo(int groupPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = groupInfo.get(groupPosition);
        if (info == null) {
            info = new GroupInfo();
            groupInfo.put(groupPosition, info);
        }
        return info;
    }

    public void notifyGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.dummyHeight = -1;
    }

    private void startExpandAnimation(int groupPosition, int firstChildPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.animating = true;
        info.firstChildPosition = firstChildPosition;
        info.expanding = true;
    }

    private void startCollapseAnimation(int groupPosition, int firstChildPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.animating = true;
        info.firstChildPosition = firstChildPosition;
        info.expanding = false;
    }

    private void stopAnimation(int groupPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.animating = false;
    }

    /**
     * Override {@link #getRealChildType(int, int)} instead.
     */
    @Override
    public final int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        if (info.animating) {
            // If we are animating this group, then all of it's children
            // are going to be dummy views which we will say is type 0.
            return 0;
        } else {
            // If we are not animating this group, then we will add 1 to
            // the type it has so that no type id conflicts will occur
            // unless getRealChildType() returns MAX_INT
            return getRealChildType(groupPosition, childPosition) + 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override {@link #getRealChildTypeCount()} instead.
     */
    @Override
    public final int getChildTypeCount() {
        // Return 1 more than the childTypeCount to account for DummyView
        return getRealChildTypeCount() + 1;
    }

    protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Override {@link #getChildView(int, int, boolean, View, ViewGroup)} instead.
     */
    @Override
    public final View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);

        if (info.animating) {
            // If this group is animating, return the a DummyView...
            if (convertView instanceof DummyView == false) {
                convertView = new DummyView(parent.getContext());
                convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0));
            }

            if (childPosition < info.firstChildPosition) {
                // The reason why we do this is to support the collapse
                // this group when the group view is not visible but the
                // children of this group are. When notifyDataSetChanged
                // is called, the ExpandableListView tries to keep the
                // list position the same by saving the first visible item
                // and jumping back to that item after the views have been
                // refreshed. Now the problem is, if a group has 2 items
                // and the first visible item is the 2nd child of the group
                // and this group is collapsed, then the dummy view will be
                // used for the group. But now the group only has 1 item
                // which is the dummy view, thus when the ListView is trying
                // to restore the scroll position, it will try to jump to
                // the second item of the group. But this group no longer
                // has a second item, so it is forced to jump to the next
                // group. This will cause a very ugly visual glitch. So
                // the way that we counteract this is by creating as many
                // dummy views as we need to maintain the scroll position
                // of the ListView after notifyDataSetChanged has been
                // called.
                convertView.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                return convertView;
            }

            final ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) parent;

            final DummyView dummyView = (DummyView) convertView;

            // Clear the views that the dummy view draws.
            dummyView.clearViews();

            // Set the style of the divider
            dummyView.setDivider(listView.getDivider(), parent.getMeasuredWidth(), listView.getDividerHeight());

            // Make measure specs to measure child views
            final int measureSpecW = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            final int measureSpecH = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            int totalHeight = 0;
            int clipHeight = parent.getHeight();

            final int len = getRealChildrenCount(groupPosition);
            for (int i = info.firstChildPosition; i < len; i++) {
                View childView = getRealChildView(groupPosition, i, (i == len - 1), null, parent);

                LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) childView.getLayoutParams();
                if (p == null) {
                    p = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();
                    childView.setLayoutParams(p);
                }

                int lpHeight = p.height;

                int childHeightSpec;
                if (lpHeight > 0) {
                    childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lpHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                } else {
                    childHeightSpec = measureSpecH;
                }

                childView.measure(measureSpecW, childHeightSpec);
                totalHeight += childView.getMeasuredHeight();

                if (totalHeight < clipHeight) {
                    // we only need to draw enough views to fool the user...
                    dummyView.addFakeView(childView);
                } else {
                    dummyView.addFakeView(childView);

                    // if this group has too many views, we don't want to
                    // calculate the height of everything... just do a light
                    // approximation and break
                    int averageHeight = totalHeight / (i + 1);
                    totalHeight += (len - i - 1) * averageHeight;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Object o;
            int state = (o = dummyView.getTag()) == null ? STATE_IDLE : (Integer) o;

            if (info.expanding && state != STATE_EXPANDING) {
                ExpandAnimation ani = new ExpandAnimation(dummyView, 0, totalHeight, info);
                ani.setDuration(this.parent.getAnimationDuration());
                ani.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        stopAnimation(groupPosition);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dummyView.setTag(STATE_IDLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                });
                dummyView.startAnimation(ani);
                dummyView.setTag(STATE_EXPANDING);
            } else if (!info.expanding && state != STATE_COLLAPSING) {
                if (info.dummyHeight == -1) {
                    info.dummyHeight = totalHeight;
                }

                ExpandAnimation ani = new ExpandAnimation(dummyView, info.dummyHeight, 0, info);
                ani.setDuration(this.parent.getAnimationDuration());
                ani.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        stopAnimation(groupPosition);
                        listView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        info.dummyHeight = -1;
                        dummyView.setTag(STATE_IDLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                });
                dummyView.startAnimation(ani);
                dummyView.setTag(STATE_COLLAPSING);
            }

            return convertView;
        } else {
            return getRealChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        if (info.animating) {
            return info.firstChildPosition + 1;
        } else {
            return getRealChildrenCount(groupPosition);
        }
    }

}

private static class DummyView extends View {
    private List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    private Drawable divider;
    private int dividerWidth;
    private int dividerHeight;

    public DummyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setDivider(Drawable divider, int dividerWidth, int dividerHeight) {
        if(divider != null) {
            this.divider = divider;
            this.dividerWidth = dividerWidth;
            this.dividerHeight = dividerHeight;

            divider.setBounds(0, 0, dividerWidth, dividerHeight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a view for the DummyView to draw.
     * @param childView View to draw
     */
    public void addFakeView(View childView) {
        childView.layout(0, 0, getWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
        views.add(childView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        final int len = views.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            View v = views.get(i);
            v.layout(left, top, left + v.getMeasuredWidth(), top + v.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    public void clearViews() {
        views.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        if(divider != null) {
            divider.setBounds(0, 0, dividerWidth, dividerHeight);
        }

        final int len = views.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            View v = views.get(i);

            canvas.save();
            canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
            v.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();

            if(divider != null) {
                divider.draw(canvas);
                canvas.translate(0, dividerHeight);
            }

            canvas.translate(0, v.getMeasuredHeight());
        }

        canvas.restore();
    }
}

private static class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
    private int baseHeight;
    private int delta;
    private View view;
    private GroupInfo groupInfo;

    private ExpandAnimation(View v, int startHeight, int endHeight, GroupInfo info) {
        baseHeight = startHeight;
        delta = endHeight - startHeight;
        view = v;
        groupInfo = info;

        view.getLayoutParams().height = startHeight;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            int val = baseHeight + (int) (delta * interpolatedTime);
            view.getLayoutParams().height = val;
            groupInfo.dummyHeight = val;
            view.requestLayout();
        } else {
            int val = baseHeight + delta;
            view.getLayoutParams().height = val;
            groupInfo.dummyHeight = val;
            view.requestLayout();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Кажется я нашел, вот есть такая строчка `dummyView.setDivider(listView.getDivider(), parent.getMeasuredWidth(), listView.getDividerHeight());` в которой в `childView` устанавливается `divider` от `group` , сейчас посмотрю как сделать чтоб устанавливался ресурс их XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сделал так в `AnimatedExpandableListView` добавил метод

```
public void setChildDivider(int iChildDividerColor)
{
    Drawable childDividerColor = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(iChildDividerColor));
    AnimatedExpandableListAdapter.setChildDividerColor(childDividerColor);
    super.setChildDivider(childDividerColor);
}
```

и в `AnimatedExpandableListAdapter` вот такое

```
private static Drawable mChildDividerColor = null;

    static void setChildDividerColor(Drawable iChildDividerColor)
    {
        mChildDividerColor = iChildDividerColor;
    }
```

Вот так применяю

```
listView.setChildDivider(R.color.black);
```

И почему то все равно нужно указывать в XML разметке тоже цвет

В итоге вот весь файл

```
public class AnimatedExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView
{
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = 
AnimatedExpandableListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * The duration of the expand/collapse animations
 */
private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 500;

private AnimatedExpandableListAdapter adapter;

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * @see ExpandableListView#setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter)
 */
public void setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter adapter)
{
    super.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Make sure that the adapter extends AnimatedExpandableListAdapter
    if (adapter instanceof AnimatedExpandableListAdapter)
    {
        this.adapter = (AnimatedExpandableListAdapter) adapter;
        this.adapter.setParent(this);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ClassCastException(adapter.toString() + " must implement AnimatedExpandableListAdapter");
    }
}

public void setChildDivider(int iChildDividerColor)
{
    Drawable childDividerColor = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(iChildDividerColor));
    AnimatedExpandableListAdapter.setChildDividerColor(childDividerColor);
    super.setChildDivider(childDividerColor);
}

/**
 * Expands the given group with an animation.
 *
 * @param groupPos The position of the group to expand
 *
 * @return Returns true if the group was expanded. False if the group was
 * already expanded.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean expandGroupWithAnimation(int groupPos)
{
    boolean lastGroup = groupPos == adapter.getGroupCount() - 1;
    if (lastGroup && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    {
        return expandGroup(groupPos, true);
    }

    int groupFlatPos = getFlatListPosition(getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPos));
    if (groupFlatPos != -1)
    {
        int childIndex = groupFlatPos - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (childIndex < getChildCount())
        {
            // Get the view for the group is it is on screen...
            View v = getChildAt(childIndex);
            if (v.getBottom() >= getBottom())
            {
                // If the user is not going to be able to see the animation
                // we just expand the group without an animation.
                // This resolves the case where getChildView will not be
                // called if the children of the group is not on screen

                // We need to notify the adapter that the group was expanded
                // without it's knowledge
                adapter.notifyGroupExpanded(groupPos);
                return expandGroup(groupPos);
            }
        }
    }

    // Let the adapter know that we are starting the animation...
    adapter.startExpandAnimation(groupPos, 0);
    // Finally call expandGroup (note that expandGroup will call
    // notifyDataSetChanged so we don't need to)
    return expandGroup(groupPos);
}

/**
 * Collapses the given group with an animation.
 *
 * @param groupPos The position of the group to collapse
 *
 * @return Returns true if the group was collapsed. False if the group was
 * already collapsed.
 */
public boolean collapseGroupWithAnimation(int groupPos)
{
    int groupFlatPos = getFlatListPosition(getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPos));
    if (groupFlatPos != -1)
    {
        int childIndex = groupFlatPos - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (childIndex >= 0 && childIndex < getChildCount())
        {
            // Get the view for the group is it is on screen...
            View v = getChildAt(childIndex);
            if (v.getBottom() >= getBottom())
            {
                // If the user is not going to be able to see the animation
                // we just collapse the group without an animation.
                // This resolves the case where getChildView will not be
                // called if the children of the group is not on screen
                return collapseGroup(groupPos);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If the group is offscreen, we can just collapse it without an
            // animation...
            return collapseGroup(groupPos);
        }
    }

    // Get the position of the firstChild visible from the top of the screen
    long packedPos = getExpandableListPosition(getFirstVisiblePosition());
    int firstChildPos = getPackedPositionChild(packedPos);
    int firstGroupPos = getPackedPositionGroup(packedPos);

    // If the first visible view on the screen is a child view AND it's a
    // child of the group we are trying to collapse, then set that
    // as the first child position of the group... see
    // {@link #startCollapseAnimation(int, int)} for why this is necessary
    firstChildPos = firstChildPos == -1 || firstGroupPos != groupPos ? 0 : firstChildPos;

    // Let the adapter know that we are going to start animating the
    // collapse animation.
    adapter.startCollapseAnimation(groupPos, firstChildPos);

    // Force the listview to refresh it's views
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return isGroupExpanded(groupPos);
}

private int getAnimationDuration()
{
    return ANIMATION_DURATION;
}

/**
 * Used for holding information regarding the group.
 */
private static class GroupInfo
{
    boolean animating = false;
    boolean expanding = false;
    int firstChildPosition;

    /**
     * This variable contains the last known height value of the dummy view.
     * We save this information so that if the user collapses a group
     * before it fully expands, the collapse animation will start from the
     * CURRENT height of the dummy view and not from the full expanded
     * height.
     */
    int dummyHeight = -1;
}

/**
 * A specialized adapter for use with the AnimatedExpandableListView. All
 * adapters used with AnimatedExpandableListView MUST extend this class.
 */
public static abstract class AnimatedExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private SparseArray<GroupInfo> groupInfo = new SparseArray<>();
    private AnimatedExpandableListView parent;

    private static final int STATE_IDLE = 0;
    private static final int STATE_EXPANDING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_COLLAPSING = 2;
    private static Drawable mChildDividerColor = null;

    static void setChildDividerColor(Drawable iChildDividerColor)
    {
        mChildDividerColor = iChildDividerColor;
    }

    private void setParent(AnimatedExpandableListView parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getRealChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getRealChildTypeCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public abstract View getRealChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);

    public abstract int getRealChildrenCount(int groupPosition);

    private GroupInfo getGroupInfo(int groupPosition)
    {
        GroupInfo info = groupInfo.get(groupPosition);
        if (info == null)
        {
            info = new GroupInfo();
            groupInfo.put(groupPosition, info);
        }
        return info;
    }

    public void notifyGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
    {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.dummyHeight = -1;
    }

    private void startExpandAnimation(int groupPosition, int firstChildPosition)
    {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.animating = true;
        info.firstChildPosition = firstChildPosition;
        info.expanding = true;
    }

    private void startCollapseAnimation(int groupPosition, int firstChildPosition)
    {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.animating = true;
        info.firstChildPosition = firstChildPosition;
        info.expanding = false;
    }

    private void stopAnimation(int groupPosition)
    {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.animating = false;
    }

    /**
     * Override {@link #getRealChildType(int, int)} instead.
     */
    @Override
    public final int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        if (info.animating)
        {
            // If we are animating this group, then all of it's children
            // are going to be dummy views which we will say is type 0.
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // If we are not animating this group, then we will add 1 to
            // the type it has so that no type id conflicts will occur
            // unless getRealChildType() returns MAX_INT
            return getRealChildType(groupPosition, childPosition) + 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override {@link #getRealChildTypeCount()} instead.
     */
    @Override
    public final int getChildTypeCount()
    {
        // Return 1 more than the childTypeCount to account for DummyView
        return getRealChildTypeCount() + 1;
    }

    protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams()
    {
        return new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Override {@link #getChildView(int, int, boolean, View, ViewGroup)} instead.
     */
    @Override
    public final View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);

        if (info.animating)
        {
            // If this group is animating, return the a DummyView...
            if (convertView instanceof DummyView == false)
            {
                convertView = new DummyView(parent.getContext());
                convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0));
            }

            if (childPosition < info.firstChildPosition)
            {
                // The reason why we do this is to support the collapse
                // this group when the group view is not visible but the
                // children of this group are. When notifyDataSetChanged
                // is called, the ExpandableListView tries to keep the
                // list position the same by saving the first visible item
                // and jumping back to that item after the views have been
                // refreshed. Now the problem is, if a group has 2 items
                // and the first visible item is the 2nd child of the group
                // and this group is collapsed, then the dummy view will be
                // used for the group. But now the group only has 1 item
                // which is the dummy view, thus when the ListView is trying
                // to restore the scroll position, it will try to jump to
                // the second item of the group. But this group no longer
                // has a second item, so it is forced to jump to the next
                // group. This will cause a very ugly visual glitch. So
                // the way that we counteract this is by creating as many
                // dummy views as we need to maintain the scroll position
                // of the ListView after notifyDataSetChanged has been
                // called.
                convertView.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                return convertView;
            }

            final ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) parent;

            final DummyView dummyView = (DummyView) convertView;

            // Clear the views that the dummy view draws.
            dummyView.clearViews();

            // Set the style of the divider
            //  dummyView.setDivider(listView.getDivider(), parent.getMeasuredWidth(), listView.getDividerHeight());
            //              dummyView.setDivider(dummyView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white), parent.getMeasuredWidth(), listView.getDividerHeight());
            dummyView.setDivider(mChildDividerColor, parent.getMeasuredWidth(), listView.getDividerHeight());

            // Make measure specs to measure child views
            final int measureSpecW = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            final int measureSpecH = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            int totalHeight = 0;
            int clipHeight = parent.getHeight();

            final int len = getRealChildrenCount(groupPosition);
            for (int i = info.firstChildPosition ; i < len ; i++)
            {
                View childView = getRealChildView(groupPosition, i, (i == len - 1), null, parent);

                LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) childView.getLayoutParams();
                if (p == null)
                {
                    p = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();
                    childView.setLayoutParams(p);
                }

                int lpHeight = p.height;

                int childHeightSpec;
                if (lpHeight > 0)
                {
                    childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lpHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                }
                else
                {
                    childHeightSpec = measureSpecH;
                }

                childView.measure(measureSpecW, childHeightSpec);
                totalHeight += childView.getMeasuredHeight();

                if (totalHeight < clipHeight)
                {
                    // we only need to draw enough views to fool the user...
                    dummyView.addFakeView(childView);
                }
                else
                {
                    dummyView.addFakeView(childView);

                    // if this group has too many views, we don't want to
                    // calculate the height of everything... just do a light
                    // approximation and break
                    int averageHeight = totalHeight / (i + 1);
                    totalHeight += (len - i - 1) * averageHeight;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Object o;
            int state = (o = dummyView.getTag()) == null ? STATE_IDLE : (Integer) o;

            if (info.expanding && state != STATE_EXPANDING)
            {
                ExpandAnimation ani = new ExpandAnimation(dummyView, 0, totalHeight, info);
                ani.setDuration(this.parent.getAnimationDuration());
                ani.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                    {
                        stopAnimation(groupPosition);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dummyView.setTag(STATE_IDLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
                    {
                    }

                });
                dummyView.startAnimation(ani);
                dummyView.setTag(STATE_EXPANDING);
            }
            else if (!info.expanding && state != STATE_COLLAPSING)
            {
                if (info.dummyHeight == -1)
                {
                    info.dummyHeight = totalHeight;
                }

                ExpandAnimation ani = new ExpandAnimation(dummyView, info.dummyHeight, 0, info);
                ani.setDuration(this.parent.getAnimationDuration());
                ani.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                    {
                        stopAnimation(groupPosition);
                        listView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        info.dummyHeight = -1;
                        dummyView.setTag(STATE_IDLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
                    {
                    }

                });
                dummyView.startAnimation(ani);
                dummyView.setTag(STATE_COLLAPSING);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
        else
        {
            return getRealChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        if (info.animating)
        {
            return info.firstChildPosition + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return getRealChildrenCount(groupPosition);
        }
    }

}

private static class DummyView extends View
{
    private List<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
    private Drawable divider;
    private int dividerWidth;
    private int dividerHeight;

    public DummyView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setDivider(Drawable divider, int dividerWidth, int dividerHeight)
    {
        if (divider != null)
        {
            this.divider = divider;
            this.dividerWidth = dividerWidth;
            this.dividerHeight = dividerHeight;

            divider.setBounds(0, 0, dividerWidth, dividerHeight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a view for the DummyView to draw.
     *
     * @param childView View to draw
     */
    public void addFakeView(View childView)
    {
        childView.layout(0, 0, getWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
        views.add(childView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        final int len = views.size();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
        {
            View v = views.get(i);
            v.layout(left, top, left + v.getMeasuredWidth(), top + v.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    public void clearViews()
    {
        views.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.save();
        if (divider != null)
        {
            divider.setBounds(0, 0, dividerWidth, dividerHeight);
        }

        final int len = views.size();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
        {
            View v = views.get(i);

            canvas.save();
            canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
            v.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();

            if (divider != null)
            {
                divider.draw(canvas);
                canvas.translate(0, dividerHeight);
            }

            canvas.translate(0, v.getMeasuredHeight());
        }

        canvas.restore();
    }
}

private static class ExpandAnimation extends Animation
{
    private int baseHeight;
    private int delta;
    private View view;
    private GroupInfo groupInfo;

    private ExpandAnimation(View v, int startHeight, int endHeight, GroupInfo info)
    {
        baseHeight = startHeight;
        delta = endHeight - startHeight;
        view = v;
        groupInfo = info;

        view.getLayoutParams().height = startHeight;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
    {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f)
        {
            int val = baseHeight + (int) (delta * interpolatedTime);
            view.getLayoutParams().height = val;
            groupInfo.dummyHeight = val;
            view.requestLayout();
        }
        else
        {
            int val = baseHeight + delta;
            view.getLayoutParams().height = val;
            groupInfo.dummyHeight = val;
            view.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}
}
```